# Android seekbar making smooth motion

Tags: android

I have a `SeekBar` whose maximum progress value is 20. Now when I reduce maximum progress value to 3 the motion of SeekBar is not smooth. And it stops at each level between 0 to 3 when I drag SeekBar. When max value is 20 it also stops but it is not noticeable as number of level are more (20).

So how I can avoid that jerk in motion when I drag `SeekBar` whose max progress value is less.
Which method In framework code related to SeekBar should I override in my SeekBAr subclass to reduce that jerk in motion to be unnoticeable.

Comment: I think you should implement your own seek bar with rubber band effect i.e. while dragging it is smooth and as soon as it is released it snaps to the nearest value.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you guide how to do it? Which method to implement.

Comment: try to use seekBar.incrementProgressBy(10); in your case when u setmax to 3 than use seekBar.incrementProgressBy(0.5);